# Grub error: unknown file system, grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, backtrack

I get the grub error unknown file system, grub rescue after I deleted my VISTA partition and allocated some unused space to make it bigger. For some reason, I am unable to boot from my Ubuntu 12 live disc, so I used my BackTrack disc and was able to mount  my ubuntu partition and was able to see all my other Windows partitions as well. Everything is intact except that the ubuntu partition shows as "31 GB Filesystem" while the other windows partitions are okay and shows as "WINXP" "WIN7"

I am also able to see the grub.cfg in the "31 GB Filesystem" partition. Anyway, how can I restore grub the easiest way using backtrack or other possible methods? Or my second choice to just get my windows to boot up? I can't burn any discs and my pc is old so it doesnt have the capability to boot from a USB. I have researched for hours and have yet to find something similar to my situation.

Please help (also I am not really a linux user, I most of the time use windows xp / 7, that's why my impt programs are there and I don't mind reinstalling Ubuntu if need be.. Would that be a possible way to restore grub as well without affecting any data loss from windows etc? Well never mind, I can't even do that because my Ubuntu live disc won't boot up. HELP!!

Comment: Please post answers as answer. I reverted your edit that removed your complete question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Try chrooting from BacKTrack (Google 'chrooting' if you don't know what I mean) and perform the command 'update-grub'.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just decided to go to my brother's house and burn Ubuntu live cd disk again and reinstalled grub